# `device.id` returns `NULL` in production, but works fine in development

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apple-push-notifications

I'm using `apn_on_rails` to send push notifications in a rails 3.0.9 application. Like so:

```
gem 'apn_on_rails', :git => 'https://github.com/natescherer/apn_on_rails.git', :branch => 'rails3'
```

I have the following method for registering device tokens:

```
# POST /iphones/register_device_token.json
def register_device_token
  @iphone = Iphone.find_or_create_by_unique_identifier(params[:unique_identifier])

  device = APN::Device.find_or_create_by_token(params[:device_token])

  logger.fatal "APN Device ID: #{device.id}"
  logger.fatal "APN Device token: #{device.token}"

  @iphone.apn_device_id = device.id

  respond_to do |format|
    if @iphone.save
      format.json { render :json => @iphone, :status => :created, :location => @iphone }
    else
      format.json { render :json => @iphone.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end

end
```

It works great in development, using `sqlite3`, but in production, using `mysql`, `device.id` returns `NULL`. Both databases are migrated to the latest version. I have no clue why this is happening and any advice on how to proceed is very much appreciated.

Comment: It's really common to have problems switching from SQLite3, which isn't SQL by a long shot, and any other dbms. MySQL has a free version. Download and use that instead of SQLite. In the meantime, look at the SQL sent to the server, run it directly (use MySQL Workbench or a command-line tool). If you still can't figure it out, edit your question and paste in the SQL DDL, sample INSERT statements, and the query rails is trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the deviceToken was sent surrounded by `<>`. `ActiveRecord` just ignored those characters and created the record without them, so the first time a device registered it worked. The problem arose when `ActiveRecord` was supposed to find the device token. `device.id` became `nil`, but `device.token` was still correct.

Anyway, when we changed the client to not send `<>` everything worked perfectly.